# How to specify a "COM" class, when multiple "COM" class has same name in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, com-interop

I have defined a `COM` interface as shown below(C#):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace CommonInterop.Hello
{
 [ComVisible(true)]
 [Guid("24484884-DAAE-4B24-B0BD-C7B9AEB3D70D")]
 public interface IComInterop
 {
    int Plus1(int x);
 }
}
```

and again almost the same interface is defined with a different **namespace** and **GUID**:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace CommonInterop.World
{
 [ComVisible(true)]
 [Guid("66664884-DAAE-4B24-B0BD-C7B9AEB34444")]
 public interface IComInterop
 {
    int Plus1(int x);
 }
}
```

**Usage in C++:**

In C++ i get the pointer to the object as show below IF only one of `COM` class is defined:

```
IComInteropPtr m_Interop;
 // and 
void SetSome(IComInteropPtr);
```

But now that i have two "COM" class that has the same class name. How can i tell C++ to use a specific "COM" class?

Im noob in C++, tell me to explain it further if the question is not specific enough.

Comment: Where is your `COM` class?  Otherwise wouldn't you just include the namespace?

Comment: I have tried; `CommonInterop::World::IComInteropPtr` but it says `IComInteropPtr ` has no member. I need to specify it using `GUID` is my guess.

Comment: A COM object is not the same as a COM interface.  COM objects are real objects that implement one or more COM interfaces.  You usually ask the COM subsystem to create the COM object that you hope implements the interface you need, then query the returned IUnknown interface for the actual interface you want.  In the code above you have only shown us part of the problem.

Comment: @RichardCritten Yea sure there exist a class that implements those "COM" interfaces, but i dont get why that has to do with this? All i'm trying to do is to specify which of this to "COM" interface must be used.

Comment: In general, names don't mean anything in COM.  Names are language implementation details and cause entirely too much interop trouble when exchanged between different languages.  At runtime, all that matters is the [Guid].  The #import directive in C++ will put the imported type definitions in a C++ namespace, its name is the same as the type library name.  C# namespace names don't mean anything at all, Tlbexp.exe removes them completely.  You'll have to write your C# code to accommodate this, another name for the interface is the simple solution.

Comment: @HansPassant I can't not change the name of the interface, because the client code also must be changed.  Is there any other way to get the class other that using ´Ptr´? by specific calling its ´GUID´?

Comment: You cannot change the C++ code??  Then how do you intend to use the different interface?  Makes no sense.  The `IComInteropPtr` type is simply an auto-generated smart pointer class name, use a C++ namespace to avoid name collisions.  Already provided by #import, you can also put the #import directive in a namespace if the auto-generated one is ambiguous.

Comment: @RayOldProf: Re-read the comments. You say "another to get the class, other than using `Ptr` ". THAT IS NOT HOW COM WORKS.

Comment: @HansPassant I think i understand you.(I hope). i thought `Ptr` was some `C++` keyword for a smartpointer. I have noticed that when there is a collision in the name, the namespace is added in front of the name. is there away to always force that` even without a name collision?. I have been looking at [#import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/298h7faa.aspx) but none of that works for me.